# What genes are driving a certain pathway

Tags: single-cell, pathway, go-enrichment, kegg

I've currently run pathway analysis on a set of genes. I'm now trying to figure out how to see which genes are driving each pathway.

```
cleaned_ductal_markers <- tumor_markers
markers15  = cleaned_ductal_markers %>% filter(cluster=="PSEUDOPAPILLARY", avg_logFC>0.5, p_val_adj<0.01)
markers15

#head(genes_map)
markers_entrez = genes_map[which(genes_map$SYMBOL %in% markers15$gene),"ENTREZID"]
kk <- enrichKEGG(gene         = markers_entrez,
                universe      = genes_map[, "ENTREZID"],
                 organism     = 'hsa',
                 pvalueCutoff = 0.05)
#head(kk)
dotplot(kk, showCategory=10)
options(repr.plot.width=7, repr.plot.height=5)
emapplot(kk, showCategory=12, font.size =16) + set_graph_style(family = "Arial Narrow", face = "plain",  text_size = 15, text_colour = "black")
```

I'm now given a list of pathways but now I'm trying to see which genes are driving those pathways.

How do I see the genes?

Comment: What’s your actual question?

Comment: @user438383 My question is how do I see which genes are driving those pathways?